# Datatype Conversion from date to varchar in mysql database table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, alter

I have a MySQL database with one table named **Invite**. This table has one column named **date** with datatype date.  I want to convert that column to *varchar*; Will the data be reset or remain as it is after this datatype change?

Comment: why don't you try it? you can TRIVIALLY set up a table with a single datetime field and then alter it to a varchar and see what happens. but why would you want a varchar date? you lose all benefit of having actual date/time values in the db.

Comment: this is live my friend.. and it has 1500 records..

Comment: so? what does that have to do with trying a test table? You can even populate that test table with the exact same values you have in the live table.